# Как скачать и сохранить аудио с сервера?

Tags: ios, objective-c, аудио

Хочу сделать музыкальный проигрыватель. Но не знаю как можно скачать файл с облака и сохранить на устройстве. Помогите пожалуйста с решением этой проблемы.

код:

AudioPlayer.m

```
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer


- (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension
{
NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFile withExtension:fileExtension];
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
}


- (void)playAudio {
[self.audioPlayer play];
}


- (void)pauseAudio {
[self.audioPlayer pause];
}


- (BOOL)isPlaying {
return [self.audioPlayer isPlaying];
 }


-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
float seconds = lroundf(value) - (minutes * 60);

int roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
int roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                  roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];
return time;
 }

 - (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value {
[self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:value];
 }


 - (NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime {
return [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
 }


 - (float)getAudioDuration {
return [self.audioPlayer duration];
 }


 @end
```

AudioPlayer.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

  @interface AudioPlayer : UIViewController

  @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

 - (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension;
 - (void)playAudio;
 - (void)pauseAudio;
 - (BOOL)isPlaying;
 - (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value;
 - (float)getAudioDuration;
 - (NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value;
 - (NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime;
```

ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
[self setupAudioPlayer:@"gendel-allilujjja-(mp3-crazy.com)"];
    NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0EJbcHq3ZALWUo0a05LMWNzeDg";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"gendel-allilujjja-(mp3-crazy.com)"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

 }


 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
 {
return NO;
 }


 - (void)setupAudioPlayer:(NSString*)fileName
 {

NSString *fileExtension = @"mp3";

[self.audioPlayer initPlayer:fileName fileExtension:fileExtension];
self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];


self.timeElapsed.text = @"0:00";

self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                      [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]]];

 }


 - (IBAction)playAudioPressed:(id)playButton
 {
[self.timer invalidate];
if (!self.isPaused) {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_pause.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

    [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
    self.isPaused = TRUE;

} else {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
    self.isPaused = FALSE;
  }
 }

 - (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
if (!self.scrubbing) {
    self.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
}
self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                      [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
    self.isPaused = FALSE;
 }
 }

 - (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber {
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

[self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];
self.scrubbing = FALSE;
 }


 - (IBAction)userIsScrubbing:(id)sender {
self.scrubbing = TRUE;
 }


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 }

 @end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) AudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *currentTimeSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *duration;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeElapsed;


@property BOOL isPaused;
@property BOOL scrubbing;

@property NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ваш audioPlayer это какой класс?

Comment: Добавил полный код.

Comment: сохраненный файл не является частью bundle, и чтоб его загрузить надо обратиться в documents. добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну допустим скачать можно вот так

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.cloud.com/music.mp3";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"music.mp3"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Загрузить, и начать играть

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"music.mp3"];

self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: Поставил прямую ссылку на скачивание, но трек не воспроизводится.
Когда добавляю трек в проект - все нормально.

Comment: так с чем у вас проблема? скачать или воспроизвести, или чтоб вам просто все написали?

Comment: Зачем все писать? Я только прошу решить одну проблему. Сделал все как вы написали выше - значит файл скачивается, но не воспроизводится. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ну показывайте как вы его воспроизводите

Comment: добавьте в вопрос - с таким форматированием я до завтра это читать буду

Comment: Да, уже добавил.